# Angular cannot get document id

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get the document id of my collection's documents.
To do so i created this:

```
  this.afs.collection("Blogs").valueChanges().map(document => {
    return document.where('title','==','test')(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();//Here is your content
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;//Here is the key of your document
      console.log('documentsId', id)

    });
  });
}
```

unfortunately it doesnt work but i dont receive an error as well.

Comment: What is the data? Can you mention it also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `valueChanges()` function is going to return an observable, to get a value from an Observable you must subscribe to it:

```
this.afs.collection("Blogs").valueChanges().subsricbe(val => {
  console.log(value);
  // and do your stuffs
})
```

Comment: It does not return the document id, it return depend on what your collections is, but subscribe to it is how to make the data started to flow

Comment: and how can i return the id?

Answer (score 2):

You are using piece of code that only works for `snapshotChanges`. **[`valueChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges)** only returns the object data if no id provided. Giving id as parameter should work in the [latest version](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/2113) of `angularfire` according to the documentation.

But for your case it wouldn't work, you don't know the id I assume. So like the documentation suggests, if you need metadata, use **[`snapShotChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges)** Also I would assume you are using rxjs version with pipeble operators, if so, use `pipe`. Also your code looks a bit off with the `ref`. Try:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

return this.afs.collection('Blogs', ref => ref.where('title','==','test'))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(docs => docs.map(a => {
       const data = a.payload.doc.data(); // Here is your content
       const id = a.payload.doc.id; // Here is the key of your document
       console.log('documentsId', id);
       return {id: id, ...data }
     })
    )
  )
```

And remember to subscribe to this function in the component.

Comment: i'm getting the error: payload does not exist on type

Comment: payload doesn't exist on type "what"?

Comment: type 'DocumentChangeAction<{}>[]'.

Comment: Where have you declared that?

Comment: i havent declared it anywhere. I just replaced my code with your code but payload cannot be found. Do i have to change something?

Comment: Updated answer: Try now... an array is returned, not an obj. My mistake ;)